# Unable to connect to container in Gitlab CI in my free account

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, eventstoredb

I have a free account of gitlab.
I also have a company account (not sure which plan).

I have the exact same project, a wrapper on EventStore.

In the CI pipeline I want to spin up a container with event store so that I can run some integration tests against it.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` that restores, compiles, runs tests and publishes nuget packages

```
#Stages
stages:
  - ci
  - pack

#Global variables
variables:
  GITLAB_RUNNER_DOTNET_CORE: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
  EVENT_STORE: eventstore/eventstore:release-5.0.2
  NUGET_REPOSITORY: $NEXUS_NUGET_REPOSITORY
  NUGET_API_KEY: $NEXUS_API_KEY
  NUGET_FOLDER_NAME: nupkgs

#Docker image
image: $GITLAB_RUNNER_DOTNET_CORE

#Jobs
ci:
  stage: ci
  services:
    - $EVENT_STORE
  variables:
    # event store service params testing with standard ports
    EVENTSTORE_INT_TCP_PORT: "1113"
    EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT: "1113"
    EVENTSTORE_INT_HTTP_PORT: "2113"
    EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT: "2113"
    EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PREFIXES: "http://*:2113/"   
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build --configuration Release
    - dotnet vstest test/*Tests/bin/Release/**/*Tests.dll

pack-beta-nuget:
  stage: pack
  script:
    - export VERSION_SUFFIX=beta$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - dotnet pack *.sln --configuration Release --output $NUGET_FOLDER_NAME --version-suffix $VERSION_SUFFIX --include-source --include-symbols -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg
    - dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg --api-key $NUGET_API_KEY --source $NUGET_REPOSITORY
  except:
    - master

pack-nuget:
  stage: pack
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet pack *.sln --configuration Release --output $NUGET_FOLDER_NAME
    - dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg --api-key $NUGET_API_KEY --source $NUGET_REPOSITORY
  only:
    - master
```

As you can see, I spin up the event store container.

From my integration tests I try to connect to the container within the CI using the following connection string:
`"ConnectTo=tcp://admin:changeit@127.0.0.1:1113; HeartBeatTimeout=500;";`

With my work account it works fine, there is a container listening on 127.0.0.1 on port 1113 and I can connect to it using the above connection string.

With my free personal account it is unable to connect.

**Why?**

I suspect it has something to do with the way docker is available on both gitlab CI runners, but why is different?

And more important, **how can I configure event store on my personal CI pipeline** on my free account so that I can connect to it if the localhost is not a valid host Uri for whatever reason?

Comment: no answers despite a bounty :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have not provided any details but it seems you're using the Docker executor. In that case, services *are not* available on `localhost` but only accessible as service aliases.

This is an extract from the working CI file:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test
  variables:
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Testing
    EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT: 2113
    EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT: 1113
    EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS: all
    EVENTSTORE_START_STANDARD_PROJECTIONS: "true"
    EventStore__ConnectionString: ConnectTo=tcp://admin:changeit@eventstore:1113
  services:
    - name: eventstore/eventstore:latest
      alias: eventstore
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
      - tags
```

For this to work, your `appsettings.Testing.json` file needs to point to `ConnectTo=tcp://admin:changeit@eventstore:1113`.

If you want to keep using the appsettings file with the configuration that points to `localhost`, you can override the setting using env variable in the CI file. Just remember to add environment variables as the configuration source. The code snippet above has such an override, matching our settings structure:

```
{
  "EventStore": {
    "ConnectionString": "ConnectTo=whatever"
  }
}
```

If you ever decide using the Kubernetes executor, you will need to revert to using `localhost`, because Kubernetes executor creates one pod per build with multiple containers, including all service containers. There's an open issue to support service aliases with Kubernetes runners, I think it will be like 12.9 or 13, pretty soon. That being said, using service aliases is a safe, future proof way of making it all work.

P.S. Just noticed that your setup works with one account and doesn't work with another. My guess would be that you either use different executors (Docker doesn't work and Kubernetes works) or different GitLab versions (if the service alias issue has already been fixed).

Comment: Didn't know about these executors. I moved to Azure DevOps and left gitlab but this is a valid answer, thank you.

Comment: I'd say you made a mistake :) It's your choice, of course. I understand it can be frustrating not getting something to work. I experienced similar issues myself but I was always able to find an issue reported by someone else at GitLab own issue tracker.

Comment: It's not permanent. I enjoyed gitlab back then, despite spending a few days frustrated with this issue in a private repo. I try to keep my CI/CD pipelines scripts very linux-ish without using built-in Microsoft/Azure only features so I can move back anytime to GitLab or GitHub. But I must say Azure DevOps pipelines has improved a lot and it now embraces the same approach as GitLab with multistage pipelines. If I get a free private nuget repo outside Azure DevOps I might switch again :)  Thanks again.

Comment: I've just seen GitLab now has nuget repo. Great news

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/484041/alexey-zimarev

I gave GitLab another try and found some undesirable issues with the way their brand new nuGet repos work. If interested, please visit
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418043/unable-to-push-nuget-packages-to-gitlab-with-dotnet-cli-due-to-unauthorized-erro